# Django argparse: Unrecognized Arguments --settings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, command-line-arguments

I've looked at the other SO threads about unrecognized argparse arguments, but none of them seem to match up with my situation.

Here's my argparse code, located at `apps/create_pdf/management/commands/create_pdf.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'html to pdf for specified website.'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        print('cp#1')

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='html to pdf for specified website')
        parser.add_argument('-w', '--website', nargs =1, action = 'store', choices = ['SITE_1', 'SITE_2'], default='', help='site to be scraped.')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        print(args)
        breakpoint()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('cp#2')

        # create_pdf_from_html()
```

I run this from the terminal like so:

```
python3 manage.py create_pdf --website=SITE_1 --settings=server_config.settings
```

...and I'm getting this error:

> manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: create_pdf --settings=server_config.settings

The settings path is correct and if I'm not using argparse, everything runs fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to add arguments to your command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'html to pdf for specified website.'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('-w', '--website', nargs =1, action = 'store', choices = ['SITE_1', 'SITE_2'], default='', help='site to be scraped.')


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print(options['website'])

        # create_pdf_from_html()
```